# Why I cant use the value of a static variable?

Tags: java, variables, static

```
    public class Test{

            static String symbol;

        public static void main (String[] args){

            String symbol = args[0];

            letter();

        }
        static void letter(){
            System.out.println(symbol);

        }
}
```

Why every time i try to run this the method letter successfully runs but prints Null? I just want to have one variable for all methods so that they can use its value.

Comment: By declaring `String symbol`, you're declaring a new method-level reference. Use `symbol = args[0]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `String symbol = args[0];` in the main method you are declaring a *new* local variable, which shadows (hides) the static field called `symbol`. When you call `letter` that local variable is no longer applicable (since it is only applicable to `main`) and thus the value of the static field is printed, but that value is `null` since that static field was never assigned.

Change that line to `symbol = args[0];` so it stores the value of `args[0]` to the static field instead.

Comment: Thanks maan  I just spent 1 hour of checking and trying everything but that..